# Connect iPad app to workstation that shares it's internet connection with another

Tags: networking, ipad

I have the iPad Air with an app "Cubase iC Pro". The idea is this app controls software "Cubase 7.5" installed on a separate workstation. When I first launch this app on my iPad I'm asked for an IP address to link up with the workstation. However the workstation I want to target is (what I would describe as) a "slave" within a "Internet shared connection" set-up.

IPConfig in cmd gives me an IP address that doesn't work (192.168.137.42). Nor does the target workstation appear on the BT home hub network page to extract the IP address that way.

Slave/target workstation: window 7
Master workstation: Windows 8

Any thoughts?

Comment: if the ipad is connected on the same network via wifi, i don't see how connecting to that LAN ip is not going to work.

Comment: Well the app on the iPad times out. But I suppose I don't really know what the correct IP address is. I've tried both the master workstation's IP address, and the IP address show in IPConfig on the Slave workstation, neither work. Is there a way to make the slave workstation appear in the home network?